# Reading values from specific range of cells using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm quite new to `PHPExcel`. What I want to do is to read some cells from an excel spreadsheet below is a sample spreadsheet, with highlighted section showing the part to read
[image: excel spreadsheet example]

I've already done some necessary initialization:

```
  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far apart from loading the file? Anyway I'm not sure if there is any phpexcel comfort function to read the whole area; perhaps you may loop through the file and read the value of each cell, that's the basic idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten a work-around for the problem which works...

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename); // load filename into PHPExcel object
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('CA1');
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        $row_index = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 5
        $col_name = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g. B
        $col_index = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($col_name); // e.g. 1 (which is equivalent to B)


        for($row =4; $row <= $row_index; $row++){                
            for($col=1; $col<=$col_index; $col++){
                echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue().' ';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Worksheet's rangeToArray() method to transfer the content of a range of cells to a PHP array:

```
$myDataArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('B4:N7', NULL, True, True);
```

Arguments to the method are:

```
 * @param string $pRange Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param mixed $nullValue Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param boolean $calculateFormulas Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param boolean $formatData Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param boolean $returnCellRef False - Return a simple array of rows and columns 
 *                                       indexed by number counting from zero
 *                               True -  Return rows and columns indexed by their 
 *                                       actual row and column IDs
```

Comment: Thanks, this method is also cool. I'd done a workaround before seeing this post. But for my problem, the columns are dynamic i.e. may not just end at 'N7'

Comment: If the columns are dynamic, you work out the range and build a string like `'B4:N7'`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this **without** loading the file? Couse when I load the file its bring the 'Allowed memory size' issue.

Comment: @AleOtero93 - Then only load the part of the file that you need, or use cell caching, or any fo the documented methods of reducing memory usage.... but if you want to read data from a spreadsheet file, then you have to load at least some of that file

Comment: @AleOtero93 - And you've been a member of StackOverflow long enough to know that if you want to ask a question, then you should ask it as a question, and not as a comment against an answer to a vaguely related question

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Asking new question then, thanks @MarkBaker